# jQuery.click() and fancybox strange behaviour on firefox - commands executed in wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, events

I purchased ready template on. However I noticed very strange behaviour on firefox.

Code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sns-imgfield-open').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var _btn = $(this);
        var href = baseUri;
        console.log(href); // Call 1
        href += 'modules/snsnovatheme/filemanager/dialog.php';
        href += '?ad_basename='+ad_basename+'&type=1';
        href += '&field_id='+_btn.attr('data-field_id');
        console.log(href); // Call 2
        $.fancybox({ // Fancybox call 3
            'width'     : 900,
            'height'    : 600,
            'minHeight' : 600,
            'href'      : href,
            'autoHeight': true,
            'type'      : 'iframe',
            'autoScale'     : false
        });
    });
});
```

On Chrome execution order is: `Call 1, Call 2, Call 3`
On Firefox It's `Call 3, (2-3 seconds wait) call 1, call 2`

*I determine execution of calls by what I see. When Loading of Fancybox appears and when text outputs to console.*

Also, when I comment out `.fancybox()` call. Call 1 and 2 are delayed.

Also, Fancybox endlessly loads on Firefox and does not produce any error nor does any XHR.

This element has only one event assigned to it.

What could be a problem here. Everything works fine on IE nad Chrome, but not on Firefox.

**Edit: Credentials** *- will remove after problem solved since it will case to exist under this url in few days.*
URL: http://unstable.seigi.eu/basenyogrodowe.co/admin9442csvph/
Login: test@test.pl
Pasword: testtest (had to have 8 chars)

When you enter SNS Theme > SNS Nova Theme and then on tab "Header" you will see Custom logo and browse button (folder icon). On firefox it loads endlessly... on IE and Chrome works fine.

Comment: Are you working locally or do you have something for us to test it out on?

Comment: Sure thing, Added temp credentials to qeuestion.

Comment: @Grimbode Were you able to spot anything? :)

Comment: Hello. Yes I checked out your link yesterday, however I got lost. I will check it out again when I have time ( probably tomorrow )